# Href - File Name taken from mysql database

Tags: mysql, pdf, unique-id

I currently have a form that uploads the data via PHP to a PDF form and that form is generated and saved on my ftp server. The data is also posted to a mysql database and the name of the file name for the pdf is the unique id of the mysql record (eg. 85124.pdf)

I would like to set up a link where the user can print the generated PDF file as a receipt but cannot figure out how to have the link call up the specific file for that specific record.

For example:

[pdf](/filename.pdf) - where the filename would be the same as the unique mysql id (eg. 85124). Is this possible?

---

I see that I may not have stated properly what I am trying to do and in what enviornment.

I have a page set up where users/clients can book their shipments online ( I work for a small shipping company). The user puts in their shipping adress and such and once they hit the submit button the following happens:

The data is sent to a mysql database on my host (godaddy) and the table is populated with that specific record. The unique id becomes the tracking number for the shipment.

```
$tracking=mysql_insert_id;
```

The data is also sent as a FDF file to my ftp and stored in a folder. The name of the FTP is determined by what the the tracking number is after it is put into the mysql database.

```
$fdf_file=$tracking().'.fdf';
$fdf_dir=dirname(__FILE__).'/results';
```

The data is then placed into a PDF form that is on my ftp.

```
$pdf_doc='https://www.mysite.com/shipformrso.pdf';
```

On the screen after the form is submitted the client receives a confirmation that their from was completed properly and they are given their tracking number.

```
echo "<font color='red' size='+1'><b>" . 'Your tracking number is '.$tracking() . '. <n\> PLEASE PROCEED TO THE SERVICE DESK TO RECOVER YOUR LABELS.' ."</b></font>";
```

What I would like to do is have another link where the user can click on and have the browser open up the FDF/PDF file was generated for their specific shipment. This is where I have the problem. I can't seem to figure out how to create the link specific file that was just generated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: does the ID have to be a secret, or do you just want to prevent unauthorized users from downloading the file? you can either choose lengthy pseudo-random filenames, or write a PHP script to send the file only after authenticating, or keep using an ID but add a secret key as well

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, you don't want to show the pdf printing link to your users? At least, the id of the pdf file, which is plainly holded in the db? Then, you can `hash` your id, `POST` it to the server and decrypt it on server side then proceed to pdf showing/printing page. In this way no user can understand the hash data, and how to decrypt it. Only your server side script does.;)

For ex:

When user enters here:

```
blabla.com/?id=SOME_HASHED_VALUE
```

On the server side:
You decrypt it, and make the `SOME_HASHED_VALUE` to look like this: 45869 - which is the unique id holded in the db. And then proceed normal flow. ;)

Comment: "hashes" by definition can't be decrypted. and if you want to decrypt something client-side, then the client can easily do so himself by looking at the JS.

Comment: I think you kind of misunderstood my answer, I said, encrypt a value (on the server side of course), put it in a from input, or a href, then POST or GET it to the server and then decrypt it on the `SERVER SIDE`.

Comment: My bad. But if you're going to go through all that trouble why not generate a completely separate unique key for the file, and forget all the encrypting/decrypting and remove any possibility of the client reverse-engineering the encryption?

Comment: May be, but I think any plainly holded unique values in a db shouldn't be shown to user directly - there must be a different view about what a user see and what a server understand. Cause by the former way, in the time when a session hijacked or any other privilege is escalated, a user(this time attacker) can view a pdf file which he is not authorized to view - for ex: by simply incrementing the unique key by one which is shown to user in the link

Comment: Should have made myself more clear...I didn't mean simple integer, I meant a long complex cryptographically secure and unique string. You won't be able to simply increment it. That said, I still prefer actually performing authentication before serving up the file but it adds overhead.

Comment: Ok, now I got it :) That's actually more likely to be system-friendly ;)

Comment: I see that I wasn't too clear as to what I was trying to accomplish so have edited my original question.